# Screen Flickering in VMWare Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a problem within using WMWare Workstation.
Sometimes, the VMWare screen is flickering occasionally. It happens in time gaps of extimated 30-45min. It flickers about 10 times in 5 seconds. I could not identify any dependencies to my actions on the VM.
Does anyone know if it could depend on too weak hardware?

System Specs:
Operating system: MS Windows 10 Enterprise
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2904 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 620
RAM: 16 GB
and enough SSD space

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was about to disable "Accelerate 3D graphics", when I noticed that VMware automatically set Graphics Memory to 32MB!!!

Set it to 1GB or 2GB and you will be good. Go to the "VM" menu, then "Settings" (or just hit Ctrl+d), then under the "Display" Device, locate and change Graphics Memory.

Comment: Why would setting less memory remove flicker ?